# plotting points on shapefile

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot some points on a a map generated from a shapefile, but can't understand why they are not being plotted correctly on the map.

```
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)


# load shapefile 

np_dist <- readShapeSpatial("~/world/coastlines_z1.shp")  #http://data.openstreetmapdata.com/coastlines-generalized-3857.zip
plot(np_dist)  


##### add points

points <- data.frame(lat = c(55.4, 35.8, 36.4), lon = c(-5.5, -5.6, -35.8))
points <- SpatialPoints(points)

plot(points, add= TRUE , col = 'red')
```

Comment: I figured out what the error was, the two data sets have different coordinate systems hence the points were being plotted, but on the wrong location. I'm trying to convert the shapefile to a different coordinate system, but cannot find clear documentation on it. Anyone can help?

Comment: See `sp::spTransform()`